# can't update the node js version and npm version

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I update my npm version to 6.9.0, after that i can't create react app. most of the commands are not working. so i uninstall the node js and reinstall that (latest version). when i try `node --version` it show version as `v6.4.0` and npm version as `6.9.0` but i want to change node version to 10.15.3 and npm version as `6.4.1` 
how to fix this issue

Comment: if you type `which node` and `which npm` what directory are these running from?

Comment: @tagyoureit which node --->**/Users/gowtham/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/node**
which npm --->**/Users/gowtham/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/bin/npm**

Comment: use `nvm` to manage different node.js version on the same machine. https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm

Comment: i used nvm only. but when i close and reopen the terminal node start refers the older version(v6.4.1).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that you have a second Node (v6.4.0) installation under `/Users/gowtham/.nvm/`.
Just remove that directory.

```sh
rm -r /Users/gowtham/.nvm/
```

Like [Zuriel suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55938326/cant-update-the-node-js-version-and-npm-version/55938596?noredirect=1#comment121874329_55938596) below, using `nvm` to switch the version of Node used or switching back to the system version are other options.

Comment: rm -rf /Users/gowtham/.nvm/ (or) . rm -rf /Users/gowtham/.nvm/v6.4.0 ?

Comment: You could do `rm -r /Users/gowtham/.nvm/versions/node/v6.4.0/` too but I guess you don't need `nvm` at all (in which case the first one as there might be other versions installed as well underneath)

Comment: now `which node` ---> `/usr/local/bin/node`,   `which npm` ---->`/usr/local/bin/npm`
is that right?

Comment: in the question i attach the screenshot. could you please confirm that everything is right?

Comment: Looks fine. Those are the versions you wanted, right?

Comment: One small suggestion nvm allows you to install multiple version of node and switch seamlessly.

Comment: this isn't the only way to fix the issue and I think that its more beneficial in a professional work environment to use nvm.  the real fix for this question is that he had nvm (node version manager) installed and what he needed to type was `nvm use system`  then his global nvm would use whatever he installed at his system level.   alternatively he could have queried nvm for a version listing of all available node versions and installed the appropriate one.

Comment: True. But the choice of tools does not define whether a work environment is "professional" or not. And this question is from 2019 when `nvm` was is such a state that removing it was the best advice. Perhaps it has improved since? In 2019 there were much better `node` version managers out there.